# How to create Budget Alarm in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm new to AWS and its services.

Let's say we have a budget of $10,000 for each environment(dev, test, prod) in AWS.
I need to send a notification for each environment in AWS as the billing reaches its threshold.

Can someone please help me is the efficient way to do the same manually in AWS?
Also, I need to implement the same using Terraform. Can someone guide me through this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How about billing alarm of AWS Budgets.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How can I do the same? Is this https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-budgets/ the correct link?

Comment: This blog is good to read. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/manage-cost-overruns-part-1/

Comment: Thank you! Could you please share a good read for doing the same using Terraform?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so familiar with terraform. Maybe official documents is good?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html#turning_on_billing_metrics

And with terraform check out if this is something you are seeking :-
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/binbashar/cost-billing-alarm/aws/latest
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/binbashar/cost-billing-alarm/aws/latest/examples/cloudwatch-billing-alert-to-pre-existing-sns-consolidated-acct